# How can I port forward in localhost

Tags: port, port-forwarding

I want to forward the packets from a port to another port within the localhost

How can I port forward from 127.0.0.1:3490 to 127.0.0.1:4490 ?

Comment: What OS are you using, and if you could explain why you want to do this their might be simpler approaches than port forwarding.

Answer (score 2):

You need a proxy server or other program that is listening on `127.0.0.1:3490` and forwarding traffic to `127.0.0.1:4490`.

Windows, try [Trivial Proxy](http://www.xrayapp.com/trivialproxy/).  Linux, check your distribution for `rinetd`.

Under Linux, it's completely possible to do this with `iptables` - probably looking at using the `REDIRECT` target in the `PREROUTING` `nat` table.

Comment: Do you have a working download link by any chance? Original page seems down (also as to per some old comments on other side for some time now), same with the usual freeware-hubs, which only point to the original (non-functional) page.

Comment: Ahh, that sucks, it was a pretty simple and straightforward utility.  Well, I suggest Luigi Auriemma's `stcpipe` - it's command line but has some additional neat features like being able to observe connections live on stdout and such: http://aluigi.altervista.org/mytoolz.htm

Answer (score 0):

You could use netcat with the following command:

```
nc -l -k 127.0.0.1 3490 -c "nc 127.0.0.1 4490"
```

Note: "The syntax depends on the `netcat` package."(look at first REF below)

REF:

https://serverfault.com/questions/512333/how-can-i-configure-netcat-or-some-other-stock-linux-utility-to-listen-on-a-sp

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/10428/simple-way-to-create-a-tunnel-from-one-local-port-to-another/101906#101906

https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/423407/how-can-i-keep-netcat-connection-open